# HATEOAS and server state

Tags: rest, hateoas

Trying to understand REST HATEOAS:

Suppose I have a service that has state; they are: initial, ready, running.  I have a client that connects to the service, obtains a page with links that allow it to mutate the service state.

It uses one of the links to change the service's state and obtains another page with new links.

As long as there is 1 client, the state the client holds is identical with the service.  But if there is a second client and it changes the service's state, the first client's representation is stale.

How is this resolved in HATEOAS?  From what I've read it seems that REST is not applicable and I should maybe look at something else.  If so, what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not resolved by HATEOS (entirely). As REST is stateless this is kind of a paradox use case to keep state in client and server aligned.

Assuming I understand your requirements, yes, you're state in client 1 is stale and not the same as the one on the server. But what if the client would make a periodic call to the server to see whether some other client changed it? If so, with HATEOAS you could provide a link to serve the current state and omit the link to change the state.

Answer (score 0):

@Kay - Thanks for answering.

I'm going to try to answer my own question.  I realized after reading your answer that the "application" in HATEOAS is really the virtual application the client experiences when it retrieves and processes the resources it gets from the server.  Its states are the pages (resources) it transitions between.  The server (service?) may have its own state but it's not the same as the client's.

As long as this distinction is kept in mind, it is not unRESTful to have stale links in client 1.  The server simply responds with new links reflecting its own state.  And the client makes new transitions based on the updated links.

Still trying to understand.  If I have it wrong, I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: That sums it up more or less

Answer (score 0):

The stateless requirement of REST refers to the ability of the server to understand and process the client request independent from any previous interactions it has made with said client. In other words, the client should be able to send a request "out of the blue" to the server (I.e.,  without a session saved on said server) and have the request processed. Hence there isn't a concept of login and logout in a purely RESTful architecture.

That's a different constraint than HATEOAS. Basically, "hypermedia as the engine of application state" means that all state is conveyed through the media type being used and not the connection itself. The client can (and often does) keep its own state, and can request snapshots of the state of resources from the server through resource representations (a.k.a media types).

If you want to be notified when a resource changes state, REST is (probably) the wrong choice. You'd likely want to use a different application protocol than, say, HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

As Fielding says: it's not REST without HATEOAS. Don't call your service REST if it's ignore HATEAOS and stateful service can not be REST. You understood HATEOA. The server provides hyperlinks for the client which should be use to change the state located at the CLIENT SIDE.

To solve your problem: omit tend server from any state information. It will easier your life. Then implement REST as using the Richardson Maturity Model while consider information's from here.